# formula for summation notation involving variable powers

Tags: notation, summation

I need help finding the formula for this summation notation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k^{2k}  }$$
or $$1^2 + 2^4 +3^6 +.....+n^{2n} $$

And preferably not involving calculus.

Comment: I don't even know how to do it for $k^k$; is there a question on Math.SE about that one (may be helpful)?

Comment: Not every sum has explicit form.

Comment: Are you implying that this particular sum is necessarily not summable ?

Comment: @user29619: that a series is not summable or that it does not have a nice closed form expression are two completely different things.

Answer (score 5):

This probably doesn't have a nice closed form, since the simpler sum of $k^k$ (called the ["hypertriangular function of $n$"](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf)) doesn't.

There is [no OEIS entry for the sums as a sequence with increasing $n$](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C17%2C746&language=english&go=Search). The [OEIS entry for the related sum of $k^k$ lists a result for the ratio of consecutive terms](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C32%2C288&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

If $$a_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^k$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=e$$

At best, you can hope for a similar asymptotic result for your sum.