# Given a closed form for a series, what can be said about the sum of the squares of its terms?

Tags: summation, closed-form, sums-of-squares

Suppose I have an integer sequence $\{a_k\}$, and suppose I know a closed form in terms of $n$ for this sum:

$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k$$

Given this, is it always (or ever) possible to find a closed form in terms of $n$ for

$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k^2$$

or to say anything about this sum?

---

If not, what special cases allow us to extend the closed form to the sum of squares in some way?

Comment: This was inspired by [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076520/formula-for-summation-notation-involving-variable-powers) regarding a series related to the [hypertriangular function of $n$](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf).

Comment: The simplest case consists of the whole numbers and squares of whole numbers. You have $\Sigma n = n(n+1)/2$, $\Sigma n^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$. Is there a way to find the (latter) sum of squares using only the formula for $\Sigma n$?