# Sum of first $n$ terms in a power series being less than next term

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series

I came across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809000/how-to-evaluate-sum-i-1n-i2-i/) yesterday. A while ago, while playing with some numbers, I had proved

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^i < (n+1)^{n+1}  ,\, n\geq1 
$$

The proof by induction, goes as follows. Check above equation for $n=1$ and then assume

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^i < (n+1)^{n+1} \text{ for some } n \gt 1 \\
$$

Add $(n+1)^{n+1}$ to both sides and get

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^i < 2(n+1)^{n+1} \leq (n+1)(n+1)^{n+1} = (n+1)^{n+2} < (n+2)^{n+2}
$$

This completes the proof by induction.

Now, I wondered, under what conditions we could prove

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{i^m} < (n+1)^{(n+1)^m}  \text{ for some } m \geq 0 \tag{1}
$$

The proof for $m=1$ was presented at the start. The case $m=0$ is not true, because the LHS is $n(n+1)/2$ which is greater than the RHS which is $(n+1)$, for  $n \geq 3$. So somewhere $\in [0,1]$ equation $(1)$ starts being true.

So, my question is: What is the $m\in[0,1]$ above which (1) starts being true?