Using induction to prove that $1 +2 ^2+ 3 ^3 + \dots + n ^n \leq \frac{4}{e}n^n$.
I am tring to solve this exercise using induction. I have to prove that
$$
1 +2 ^2+ 3 ^3 + \dots + n ^n  \leq \frac{4}{e}n^n.
$$
One hint is to use the properties of the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$. However I am having some problems: I got stuck in this chain of inequalities.
$$
1 +2 ^2+ 3 ^3 + \dots + n ^n + (n+1)^{n+1} \leq \frac{4}{e}n^n + (n+1)^{n+1}.
$$
Here I do not know how to proceed. I have tried using the fact that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ is decreasing to $e$, but I cannot get a useful estimate for $(n+1)^{n+1}$. I have also used the fact that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is increasing to $e$, obtaining the inequality $(n+1)^n \leq e n^n$, but I was not able to use this.
Could you please help me!
Thanks

I would like to draw attention to a similar question that I asked a while ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4847541/sum-of-first-n-terms-in-a-power-series-being-less-than-next-term

For the inductive step you need to show that
$$
\frac{4}{e}n^n + (n+1)^{n+1} \le \frac{4}{e}(n+1)^{n+1} \\
\iff \frac{4}{e}n^n \le \frac{4-e}{e}(n+1)^{n+1} \\
\iff \frac{4}{(4-e)(n+1)} \le \left( 1 + \frac 1n\right)^n \, .
$$
The last inequality is true for all $n \ge 1$:
$$
\frac{4}{(4-e)(n+1)} \le \frac{4}{(4-3)(1+1)} = 2 \le \left( 1 + \frac 1n\right)^n
$$
since $e < 3$ and $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing in $n$.
Remark: The factor $4/e \approx 1.47$ can be replaced by the smaller factor $5/4 = 1.25$, which is best possible. The inductive step is the same, but you'll need to prove it for the base cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.
